# Redirect all requests to subfolder

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess

I have a website on a shared hosting and I would like to redirect all calls to a subfolder.

E.g.:

```
www.xxx.com/a/b/c
```

to be redirected to the  script located at:

```
/docroot/public/index.php
```

Of course I need `a/b/c` to be preserved so that the index.php script figures out what controller to invoke etc etc.

Any idea?

Answer (score 0):

Your .htaccess file should be something like this:

```
# Turn rewriting on
Options +FollowSymLinks
RewriteEngine On
# Redirect requests to index.php
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !=/docroot/public/index.php
RewriteRule .* /docroot/public/index.php
```

Then in index.php you can read all request URL parts:

```
$parts = explode('/', $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']);
// $parts is an array containing a, b, c...
```

Comment: not working :( the docroot folder is in fact the document root of the website so maybe we can exclude it? It does not work anyway though.

Comment: @nourdine You should place the .htaccess file in the root folder of your website. The path in the file should start there, so it should be /public/index.php if the docroot folder is the root of the website.

Comment: That is exactly what I did. As a matter of fact it works partially because if I hit www.xxx.com/ I see the address bar changing into www.xxx.com/public. The  problems come when I hit www.xxx.com/a/b/c as I get a 404

Comment: One last thing: is it possible to force the visible url in the address bar to not change? As though it was an internal redirect?

Comment: Yes, I think that's even the default behavior when you work with a redirect in .htaccess files. The original request URL should remain visible in the browser.